# How to make a floating window with chrome app

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

This chrome app https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/floating-for-youtube/jjphmlaoffndcnecccgemfdaaoighkel can float on any windows app

What chrome api does it use ?

Comment: It's a chrome app, which is deprecated and soon will be removed from Chrome, and it uses chrome.app.window.create. You can inspect its source code in devtools or via [crxviewer](https://robwu.nl/crxviewer/).

Comment: so it won't be possible anymore ? if yes that's a pity.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve to this result with picture in picture:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Picture-in-Picture_API

but I think it works only with videos